# How do we manipulate the stylesheet link tag generated by react-script build?

Tags: reactjs, lighthouse, react-scripts

Following what Lighthouse told me, I'm trying to eliminate "render-blocking resources", like `link` tags without `media` attribute.
One of the heavier tag is injected by `react-script` build script inside tag `head`:

```
<link href="/static/css/main.e8661b30.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is it possible to generate this tag with media attribute?

```
<link href="/static/css/main.e8661b30.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```